# android view under fragment responding to tap

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have two fragments A and B.Fragment A has a view which when clicked opens Fragment B which occupies the frame layout in activity_main.xml.The frame layout originally has  a recyclerview in it.But when simply tapped on  Fragment B the recyclerview in activity_main.xml is responding.

Fragment A:

```
public class Motels extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.motels, container, false);
        final Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Motels");
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 RippleView rippleView6=(RippleView) v.findViewById(R.id.ripple6);
        rippleView6.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView2) {
                Log.d("Sample", "Ripple completed");


                MotelVaik motelVaik= new MotelVaik();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager6=getFragmentManager();
                final FragmentTransaction transaction6= fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left_, R.anim.exit_to_right,R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left);
                transaction6.replace(R.id.frame, motelVaik);
                transaction6.addToBackStack("vaik").commit();
            }

        });}}
```

Fragment B:

```
public class MotelVaik extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.motel_vaikkom,container,false);
   return v;}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        >
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            >
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the xml of fragment B, on the root element just add

android:clickable="true"

make sure the height of the layout is match_parent

Comment: Great answer. I was also confused due to this problem